# Macbook Air blocking websites

Tags: macbook-pro

I am not tech savvy and know almost nothing about computers. Macs are even harder, so I don't know where to start.

I did the suggested update yesterday and now it is blocking me on a bunch of stuff but not all.

For instance, I can't go to facebook or my school division website, but can google, read news pages, go to yahoo mail......that is about all I do on here.

Anyhow it has also blocked my access to my portal that I had installed for work....no idea what happened, but an assuming it was the update.
any info would help.

If you could make your advice simple enough that a monkey could follow it then I might have a chance to fix it :)  Thanks

Comment: try to ping your school divisions website from within Terminal -> ping <url/of/page without http:// in front> -> what is the result? Do you get an IP of the Page or does it say Unknown Host?

Comment: Which update did you apply, where did you get it from? Are you using your computer at home or at school when the problem occurs?

Answer (score 2):

Monkey sees monkey does :)

- Assuming you are the Administrator (open system preferences- users and groups check under your profile name that says Admin.
- Now this is bit surgical, but just follow the steps (you will remove any web sites blocking)

Open Terminal app located in your utility folder (it looks like funny screen with only text in it.

To get started, Copy and paste the following code in Terminal:

```
sudo /bin/cp /etc/hosts /etc/hosts-original
```

Terminal will ask for your password. (same password that you use to log in to computer)

Now we can start editing the hosts file.

Copy and paste this code in Terminal (all one line):

```
sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit /etc/hosts
```

The hosts file will open in new window called TextEdit.

Notice the following lines and **do not delete them under any circumstances**:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

255.255.255.255 broadcasthost

::1 localhost

fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

You should **not** have any further lines after those.

If you do! just delete them. (those are the ones preventing you from accessing other websites)

When you’re done, quit TextEdit and save the hosts file when prompted.

Restart your computer.